# Search for CSS(Sencha Touch) tutorials

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to change the layout of my app. I want use my own buttons and change background color.
Can someone post some useful tutorials. I'm not so good in css

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

My only advice is for you to use Firebug if you want to customize you app.
Set `cls` attributes to your components, launch the app on a Firefox/Chrome/Safari and then just right click on the HTML element you want to customize and take a look at the CSS set for the element. Then, it's all about CSS writing.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can override the existing CSS with your own stylesheet, you can also use SCSS for theming a touch application. Take a look at this guide on SCSS http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch

Comment: Correction, it is called SASS.

Answer (score 0):

ya you can change your background colors in `touch-charts-full.css` file. In that you can able to change shape of the buttons also.If suppose you want to chnage the background color of toolbar, Search for toolbar in css file and change background color in that.